# Google Map doesn't render in whole frame when html tag hidden by default

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application, I need to make invisible the google map by default, when user click the show button it will show. My problem is when click the button the map doesn't render properly throughout whole frame.

```
 <div id="map-canvas" style="display: none"></div>
```

Here is my `javascript` function

```
 function show(){
                if(document.getElementById("showMap").value == "Show Map"){
                    document.getElementById("showMap").value = "Hide Map";
                    document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.display = '';

                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("showMap").value = "Show Map";
                    document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
```

Here is my google map loader function.

```
 function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(7.7, 80.7)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Also using some CSS.

```
  #map-canvas {
      height: 100%;
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px
   }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: trigger the `resize` event on the map once it is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

hiding the map-canvas

```
document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Showing the map-canvas

```
document.getElementById("map-canvas").style.visibility = "visible";
```

You can use JQuery - show(), hide() and toggle() to do the same.

Comment: I tried this. This way allows to take the allocated space even when the map is invisible.